# will + present continuous vs past continuous

Tags: sentence-meaning

Are sentence 1 and sentence 2 in the same meaning?

> 1. Maybe I'll be surprised, maybe they'll just blow me away with something I **am not expecting**, who knows?
> 2. Maybe I'll be surprised, maybe they'll just blow me away with something I **was not expecting**, who knows?

Answer (score 1):

There's a subtle difference in meaning between the two. So subtle that it's unlikely to matter in practice, at least in this instance.

In the first sentence, there's absolutely no question about the grammar; "something I **am not** expecting" puts the expectation in the *now*. It means something that the speaker isn't expecting at the point they say it.

The second is arguably ungrammatical, or at least inappropriate, because you're mixing the future with the past progressive. Mixing the future with the present is okay, as relating something in the future to a *present* expectation is fine. In the second, the past progressive suggests the expectation you're referring to ought to be in the past, and without some other text, possibly in another sentence, it's unclear when that time was.

If you made it "something I was not expecting **when I set the person specification**", that locates the expectation in the past at a specific point, and even handily indicates what sort of unexpected thing it might be - some skill or experience that they hadn't thought to include in the person specification, or thought to include but didn't think was likely to come up. This might relate to someone who's going to interview candidates for a job, for instance.

Leaving it as the past progressive without that sort of clarity, you have two ways I can see people taking it. They might come to some guess or assumption about when in the past it was; context might help with that. They might also read it as actually giving the same meaning as the future perfect progressive rather than the future progressive - "something I **won't have been** expecting". That is, locating the point of the expectation in the past compared to the point at which the person is to be "blown away"; without any further cues, that will tend to be read as the immediate past, right up to the moment in which they are blown away.

However, the different possible meanings of the second sentence, and the one meaning of the first sentence, are very very close for practical purposes. What they all mean is "maybe they'll just blow me away with something **unexpected**".